# Is it possible to modify the selectors of CSS rules in externally loaded style sheets?

Tags: css, browser, stylesheet

On a web page that contains an eternal CSS style sheet (loaded via `<link rel="stylesheet">`), I would like to modify the selector of one of its CSS rules. I can reference the rule with:

```
var rule = document.styleSheets[…].cssRules[…];
```

(where `…` are numbers).

Once selected, I can read its selector and other values:

```
rule.cssText // 'em { color: red }'
rule.selectorText // 'em'
rule.style.color // 'red'
```

However, when I try to write one of these, it only lets me write the `style` object:

```
// These won’t work
rule.cssText = 'em.foo { color: red }';
rule.selectorText = 'em.foo';

// This will work
rule.style.color = 'blue';
```

Why doesn’t it let me write `.cssText` or `.selectorText`? From what I see in [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/), they are *not* readonly.

**Update:** I’ve checked for inline style sheets, too. It doesn’t work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least Firefox implements them read-only.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule.cssText
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule/selectorText

Comment: I see. I’ve checked in Chrome and it does work (i.e. the selector text is modifiable).